# How to edit an image with absolute path?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, image-editing

I have use the pesdk library to edit an image.

```
public static int GALLERY_RESULT = 2;
private void selectImgtoEdit() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(path));

       startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_RESULT);
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
        openEditor(selectedImage);

}

public void openEditor(Uri inputImage) {
        SettingsList settingsList = createPesdkSettingsList();

        // Set input image
        settingsList.getSettingsModel(LoadSettings.class).setSource(inputImage);

        settingsList.getSettingsModel(PhotoEditorSaveSettings.class).setOutputToGallery(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

        new PhotoEditorBuilder(this).setSettingsList(settingsList).startActivityForResult(this, PESDK_RESULT);
    }
```

I want to use that library with the absolute path of an image. How can I setting it ?

Answer (score 1):

You should convert absolute path to content uri.

For example

Below Android P

```
public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
  String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
  Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
      MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
      new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
      MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
      new String[] { filePath }, null);
  if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
    cursor.close();
    return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + id);
  } else {
    if (imageFile.exists()) {
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
      return context.getContentResolver().insert(
          MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Above Android Q

```
public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media._ID},
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
        new String[]{filePath}, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
    cursor.close();
    return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + id);
} else {
    if (imageFile.exists()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            Uri picCollection = MediaStore.Images.Media
                    .getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
            ContentValues picDetail = new ContentValues();
            picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, imageFile.getName());
            picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
            picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,"DCIM/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING,1);
            Uri finaluri = resolver.insert(picCollection, picDetail);
            picDetail.clear();
            picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
            resolver.update(picCollection, picDetail, null, null);
            return finaluri;
        }else {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
            return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        }

    } else {
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But this Intent have the content uri. My path is the absolute path from android

Comment: You can convert absolute path to content uri too. I can post code if you want.

Comment: the content when I use this pesdk like this: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F145/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fpng/853396237.
So your code isn't work but thank you a lot, BluePine

Comment: Do you have the absolute path of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the absolute path of the image?

I suggest code like below, try again...

```
String filepath = "/storage/emulated/0/image.jpg";
Uri selectedUri = getImageContentUri(context, new File(filepath));
openEditor(selectedUri);
```

Use second getImageContentUri function in above answer.

Comment: Yeah I did but It didn't work